# Correctness of multiplication in galois field

Tags: c#, aes, galois-field, finite-field

I'm into developing code to do arithmetic in Galois field gf(2^8) and I think I'm getting wrong results on multiplication operations.

```
private static byte Multiply(byte a, byte b)
{
    byte result = 0;

    while (b != 0)
    {
        if ((b & 1) != 0)
        {
            result ^= a;
        }

        a <<= 1;
        b >>= 1;
    }

    return result;
}
```

The result for Multiply(1, 2) gives the correct value of 2 but Multiply(240, 249) gives me 112 instead of the expected 148.

Now I'm not sure if this value is good or not with Russian Peasant Multiplication.

Maybe there's another algorithm that gives correct results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example code:

```
#define POLY 0x11D

static BYTE GFMpy(BYTE b0, BYTE b1)
{
int i;
int product;
    product = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        product <<= 1;
        if(product & 0x100){
            product ^= POLY;}
        if(b0 & 0x80u){
            product ^= b1;}
        b0 <<= 1;}
    return((BYTE)product);
}
```

---

Example using lookup tables:

```c
#define POLY (0x11d)
/* all non-zero elements are powers of 2 for POLY == 0x11d */
typedef unsigned char BYTE;
/* ... */
static BYTE exp2[512];
static BYTE log2[256];
/* ... */
static void Tbli()
{
int i;
int b;
    b = 0x01;                   /* init exp2 table */
    for(i = 0; i < 512; i++){
        exp2[i] = (BYTE)b;
        b = (b << 1);           /*  powers of 2 */
        if(b & 0x100)
            b ^= POLY;
    }

    log2[0] = 0xff;             /* init log2 table */
    for(i = 0; i < 255; i++)
        log2[exp2[i]] = (BYTE)i;
}
/* ... */
static BYTE GFMpy(BYTE m0, BYTE m1) /* multiply */
{
    if(0 == m0 || 0 == m1)
        return(0);
    return(exp2[log2[m0] + log2[m1]]);
}
/* ... */
static BYTE GFDiv(BYTE m0, BYTE m1) /* divide */
{
    if(0 == m0)
        return(0);
    return(exp2[log2[m0] + 255 - log2[m1]]);
}
```

Comment: If u can explain what are these magic numbers: 0x100 and 0x80u ? And why they are used? Is it specific to only one GF ?

Comment: Multiply(240, 249) is giving me value of 119 with POLY = 0x11B. Is it correct ?

Comment: @Macko - 0x100 represents x^8. All GF(2^8) polynomials are of the form x^8 + ... + 1. 0x80 represents x^7, the most significant bit of a byte. Multiply(240,249) with POLY:0x11D = 148. Multiply(240,249) with POLY:0x11B = 119.

Comment: how to implement division in GF ?

Comment: @Macko - you could raise a number to the 254th power (x^254 == 1/x in GF(2^8)), but it would be faster to generate exponentiate and log tables (base 2). I updated my answer to show the table version.

Comment: Great, can u share some numbers for unit tests ?

Comment: @Macko - you know the multiply works, so try multiplying two numbers, then divide the product by one of the numbers and see if it returns the other number. Do this for a few numbers.

Comment: why exp2[512] is set to this lenght ?

Comment: how to implement mod and pow operation in this field?

Comment: @Macko  power - use [exponentiation by repeated squaring](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) . Modulo = number xor ((number / modulus) * modulus), since the field division rounds down. exp is 512 bytes long so a check for greater than 255 is not needed for multiply, and 255 is added for divide so a check for less than zero is not needed for divide.